# US citizen, traveling to Shanghai with Taiwan layover then a trip to Taiwan NOT for a layover. Do I need a visa?

Tags: china, transit-visas, taiwan

I will be traveling to Shanghai for 4 days from NYC through Taipei. My layover is long, about 9 hours. I will be traveling back to Taipei but this time I won't be on a layover, but rather will travel back to NYC after a week in Taiwan.

My original plan was with a layover through Chicago then direct to Shanhai, but the departure from NYC was bad, and the best I can find is through Taipei.

Will I be able to do visa-free transit, or will my layover in Taipei and then return to Taipei require me to apply for a tourist visa to visit Shanghai?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Visa policy of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_China#72-hour_stay_.2F_144-hour_stay):

> ...the outbound flight's first stop or destination must be in a different country than the inbound flight's.

This tells me that your inbound and outbound flights from and to Taipei would disqualify you from using the visa-free transit.

Comment: OK, that was my interpretation too. Thank you for giving me an independent perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Shanghai, but Taiwan should be visa-free to US passport for a long time

https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-149-4486-7785a-2.html